# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement: trying to make a clock

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple clock in javascript. But for some reason,  I keep getting this error. As far as I know there aren't any missing semicolons. Here is the code:

```
function clockGen() {
var time = new Date();
var hour = time.getHours();
var min = time.getMinutes();
var sec = time.getSeconds();
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = hour + ":" min + ":" + sec;
var refresh = setTimeout("clockGen()", 1000);
}
```

It keeps giving me the error shown in the title for some reason. Can you please get me in the right direction?

Comment: You're missing a `+`.

Comment: Okay i feel so stupid now. I am going to hide forever and ever and ever now

Comment: It is also a good practice to not use strings with `setTimeout` or `setInterval` as this can often cause unforseen problems. So you should change the `setTimeout` to `var refresh = setTimeout(clockGen, 1000);`. The reason for this is that if you provide it with a string, it will use the `eval` method in javascript, which is just generally a bad practice!!

Answer (score 0):

Your a missing a plus sign here:

```
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = hour + ":" min + ":" + sec;
```

Instead it should be:

```
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any missing semicolons. But the "missing semicolon" really means "The interpreter found what it thinks to be the end of a statement, but it didn't have a semicolon. So I don't know what to do with this code. Maybe it was supposed to be the end of a statement, maybe it wasn't. Since the author wasn't explicit, the safest option is to complain and ask them to be clearer."

Check this line:

```
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = hour + ":" min + ":" + sec;
//                                                  ^^^^^^
```